# getting the pid of a process in zsh

Tags: linux, shell, zsh

I am coding on a Red Hat Machine and I want to get the process id of a process in the interactive mode as well as the in a script.

In bash 'pidof' works but not in zsh.

What would be the equivalent of pidof in zsh ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On our various Centos (based on RedHat) machines pidof is available in zsh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may wish to `which pidof` in bash, to determine the location of `pidof`  and  then try running zsh with the absolute path.

If the above works, you just have a $PATH issue (as I have never seen `pidof` as a bash builtin.)

If that doesn't work try the following:

This is probably not a simple as you want, but it works for me:

`pgrep -U $USER some_program`

Where 'some_program' is the name you would normally supply `pidof`.

Comment: `pgrep -U $USER some_program` will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

On a RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux) machine `pidof` is located at `/sbin/pidof`. Just add `/sbin` to your path.